# Does Harley Quinn ever have children?

Tags: dc, harley-quinn

Does Harley Quinn ever have children, either with the Joker or with someone else? We see her have them in a dream sequence in the 2016 *Suicide Squad* film.

[image: Harley Quinn and the Joker dream sequence stills from Suicide Squad with them married and having a baby child]

Comment: What are these pictures of?

Comment: They're from the *Suicide Squad* movie... though I don't know why they matter here. They're from a dream sequence, if I remember correctly.

Comment: And were likely wish rather than memories

Comment: Thanks for asking this, you've helped me a lot. :) I love Harley Quinn but don't want to read anything where she has children, so someone linked me to this question and it really helped me figure out what to avoid. :)

Answer (score 77):

### In the DC Animated Universe, yes.

While we never learn anything about her actual child/children, we meet Harley's two granddaughters, [Delia and Deidre](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Dee_Dee) (together referred to as "Dee Dee").

Like their grandmother, they are gymnasts and criminals. They are members of the Jokerz, introduced in *[Batman Beyond: Return of the Joker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Beyond:_Return_of_the_Joker)*.

[image: De-De & Nana Harley]
*Delia and Diedre being chided by "Nana Harley"*

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that also in the movie the Joker and Harley "Adopted" [Spoiler], rather than going through the "Joy" of childbirth. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXMxRDpopoo

Answer (score 56):

In *Injustice: Gods Among Us* Year Two #13, Harley admits to Black Canary that she had a daughter named Lucy, fathered by Joker.

*Injustice* is a separate universe, which does not necessarily reflect the state of things in the main continuity (whatever it happens to be these days). Yet, I think there was a crossover between some main continuity and *Injustice*.

[image: Harley sitting with Canary and telling her she has a child named Lucy that lives with her sister]

In *Injustice 2* #2 she even calls the woman who is taking care of her daughter:

[image: Harley calls her sister who asks if she wants to speak to Lucy]

Comment: *Injustice: Gods Among Us* is an Elseworlds story, right? If so, then it might be worth noting that Lucy doesn't necessarily exist in main continuity.

Comment: @Thunderforge  -  I have no idea what "Elseworlds" are. I thought it was clear that I'm not talking about the main continuity, but I'll update the answer. Thanks for noticing this!

Comment: [Elseworlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elseworlds) is DC Comics' brand for alternate universe stories. I haven't read the comics, but I recall that the video game starts off with a title card saying that it takes place "Elseworld".

Comment: I think it's a [Multiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse_(DC_Comics)#Injustice) title, but I get yor point.

Comment: @Thunderforge  -  as far as I understand, it's called Multiverse since the launch of the *New 52*.

Comment: The first comic seems to imply that the Joker is the father of Lucy. Is this the case?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd She doesn't explicitly state this, to my memory (though I'll check later), but it's heavily implied that it's indeed the case (and there was no one else around at the time).

Comment: I wanted to nominate this for "favorite answer of the quarter" because it's actually of practical use to me, instead of just answering theoretical curiosity, but unfortunately I can't because it's not within the time frame allowed. :(

Comment: Wait, does an edit mean this is eligible now? :)

Comment: @Bellatrix Nah, I just added the part from the comments :) Thanks for the support though ;)

Comment: @Gallifreyan You're welcome, it's not often that an answer can actually make a practical impact for someone! :) Thanks for the help, the advice, and the link! ;)

Answer (score 28):

While I don't have a vast amount of knowledge from the comics, there is an easter-egg in the Arkham City game that involves this.

When the player first visits the Steel Mill where the Joker (together with Harley) have holed up as their hideout, a crib can be seen in the office they are using to plot:

[image: baby's crib found in the Steel Mill]

Around the crib on the floor can be seen positive pregnancy tests:

[image: positive pregnancy tests surrounding the crib]

Spoiler for the rest of the game and the DLC follows:

> Once you have completed the game, and the Joker is dead, you can revisit the Steel Mill under solely Harley's control. If you head back to the office, you can find the following scattered around:[image] This would seem to imply that - in the Arkham game universe at least - she doesn't (can't?) have children

Comment: Which, ironically, is opposite to actual pregnancy tests of that variety where negative tests eventually come up as positive due to the effects of evaporation 
http://www.modernmom.com/2c254584-051f-11e2-9d62-404062497d7e.html

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: I always considered the implication here to be that they were new ones, rather than the same ones that were present on your first visit

Comment: {nods} Possible. It does raise the Fridge Horror scenario that the reason why they're negative now was the whole Batman knocking Harley around... not that that would probably change the results that quickly.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: Yeah, it definitely introduces some pretty dark subtext doesn't it?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It can also be from the emotional shock of losing her boyfriend.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots That doesn't sound that far off to me. When I played the game, that was the assumption I immediately came to.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Joker laying on the ground surrounded by lots of weapons, alcohol, flowers and in the corner some baby stuff (baby onesies and a crib)]

I wanted to add in here, along with Harley’s Enchantress vision of kids (specifically, a boy and girl), there are baby onesies in this scene with Joker in the upper corner. One pink, one blue, and also what looks like a black one. Maybe a baby died? Her speech to Diablo about kids would make more sense now.

> Own that shit. Own it! What do you think was going to happen? Huh?... What, you were just thinking you can have a happy family and coach little leagues, and make car payments? Normal is a setting on the dryer. People like us, we don’t get normal!

Also worth mentioning, they also took a step away from Harley’s typical red/black colors and did pink/blue (baby colors) for her hair in *Suicide Squad*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Harley had a daughter whom she let her sister raise.

She left the Joker for a year to have said child because she feared that that learning he is a father would lead to a worsening in the Joker's mental state.

Her name is Lucy.

[She was referenced to in a comic](https://l7world.com/2014/07/harley-quinn-joker-daughter.html), where Harley refused to finish fighting Black Canary because Black Canary was pregnant with Green Arrow's child.

Comment: This was already mentioned (in greater detail) by Gallifreyan's answer.

Comment: @Jenayah there is no rule stating that answers can't contain the same content.

Comment: @Edlothiad which is why I hinted at adding more detail with regards to [Do we have a policy on duplicate answers?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3308/98028)

Comment: @Jenayah I'm not seeing any hints at adding more detail, am I missing a comment?

Comment: @Edlothiad granted my "in greater detail" might read ambiguous...

Comment: Well to me it reads like "Gallifreyan has provided more detail than you have."