# Is Harley Quinn physically enhanced in the Arkham games?

Tags: dc, arkham-series

In the cartoon, and I believe also in the comics, Harley's received a power-up from Poison Ivy making her stronger and tougher than the average human being, and immune to poisons. Is there any indication that she has that sort of enhanced capabilities in the *Batman: Arkham* franchise of games?

This in part came up because I was going to comment on an answer to [Does Harley Quinn ever have children?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145326/does-harley-quinn-ever-have-children) that employed references in *Arkham City* that her enhancements might prevent her from having children, as is occasionally the case in serious takes on regenerators, namely that their body might only recognize a developing baby as foreign tissue and thus "cure" them of it.

Comment: Yes, absolutely: going by eye, I'd say she has been physically enhanced by at least two sizes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no mention of her undergoing any form of "enhancement" or "augmentation" to increase her physical abilities in any of the Arkham games to the best of my knowledge.

Her strength and dexterity is attributed to her past as a gymnast rather than any form of superhuman ability (and peak human physiology is way higher than real-world analogues in all forms of DC media).

What *is* covered is her background as a psychologist who was assigned to treat the Joker in Arkham before he swayed her over to his way of thinking, as shown in the audio tapes you can find in the facility, shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPu0paAKzo8).

There is also the listing of her attributes in her in-game dossier, which reads:

> Attributes:
>
> - Surprising strength and stamina
> - Superior gymnastic skills
> - Total disregard for human life
> - Like The Joker, she is a homicidal psychotic who escapes easy classification